# Program to find Shortest Symbolic Expression

Tags: factoring, math-software, symbolic-computation

I was solving a physics problem using lots of replacements for some expressions to get a manageable equation. Finally I got my answer, but it looked more like a waterfall than an actual result : `R = f₁(P, Q) where P=f₂(A, B, C, D) where A=f₃(a, b, c) where a=f₄(R₁, R₂, R₃, R₄, R₅) and Q=[...]`.

So, I decided to express everything with the initial variables and get the best simplification I can (the intermediary steps do not have any physical meaning). I discovered the SageMath software which helped me to get a good expression (it got rid of a lot of square roots and ratios) but the returned answer was in an expanded form and I wasn't able to factorize it to get the shortest expression.

My only problem is the part inside a cubic root:
`a⁶ +6a⁵b +3a⁴b² -28a³b³ -9a²b⁴ +54ab⁵ -27b⁶ +12a⁴bc +48a³b²c -24a²b³c -144ab⁴c +108b⁵c -3a⁴c² -12a³bc² +54a²b²c² +132ab³c² -171b⁴c² -24a²bc³ -48ab²c³ +136b³c³ +3a²c⁴ +6abc⁴ -57b²c⁴ +12bc⁵ -c⁶`

It doesn't look that bad since it's just a polynomial expression, but it's huge... My problem is that I have no clue about **which software to use or how to use it to get the shortest expression of this result**. All I know is that `a+b-c` was a common pattern so it's probable that it will be in the expression : is there a software where I can input this information ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, indeed it is possible to quite simplify the expression, as it is equal to :
$$(a + 3 b - c)^3 (a - b + c)^3$$
(if I didn't make any error copying your expression).

To get this, I used mathematica and the function FullSimplify. For what I know, mathematica writes expression as trees, starting with the variables and combining them 2 by 2 with operations. It seems that FullSimplify just writes as many trees it can for the expression and chose the smallest one.

Do you have access to Mathematica ? I'm not used to Sage, but I guess it can do similar things.

**Edit :** I've seen that your expression appears in a cubic root, so I guess it is quite convenient that it is actually a cube (maybe it is not a coïncidence by the way).

Comment: Thank you. I heard about Mathematica but preferred to use a free alternative. I'll try to get a copy with a student licence if it's possible.

Comment: Yeah, I understand ... actually, I think Sage can do this kind of things too, I just don't have the software and don't know the goods functions (have you tried Factor ?). As you said, some schools and universities provide student licences for mathematica, that are almost as good as the professional one : for example, I did this computation with a student licence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this site can do it, I am not sure: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=7014d9722bc42de3f621eaad1da2615e&title=Simplifying+Algebraic+Expressions+Calculator&theme=blue&i0=9x-9y^3&podSelect